# Tags in email template editor

Tags: php

I am making a system with a email function but I want that the admin can change those email messages with the admin panel. I am planning to do this with ckeditor but I want that I can add tags where for example the user name will be placed. Something like this:

```
Dear %%name%%,

Thank you for purchasing %%item%%.

Kind Regards,
%%business%%
```

Thanks !

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I use those tags with %% %% or something similar in the website editor and that they will be replaced with a name, item etc.

Comment: Something similar like wordpress is using: http://cdn2.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/welcome-email-settings.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A part of your code could look like this:

```
$text = <text from editor>
$tokens['name'] = 'Mr. Jones';
$tokens['item'] = 'left shoe';
$tokens['business'] = 'WalkThisWay';

// match anything between '%%' than's not a control chr or '%', min 3 and max 16 chrs.
if (preg_match_all('/%%[^[:cntrl:]%]{3,16}%%/',$text,$matches))
{
  // replace all found tokens
  foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
  {
    // get token
    $tokenKey = trim($match,'%');
    // replace
    $text = str_replace($match,$tokens[$tokenKey],$text);
  }
}
```

It seeks out matching tokens and replaces them with the real content. You still need to think about how to get your `$tokens` array.